# Caps Lock LED not working

Tags: keyboard, kernel-parameters

I recently installed kernel 3.14.27-100 on my Fedora 19 system and now I no longer get a Caps Lock LED when using virtual terminals. (It still works on X system ). Also, it works fine running kernel 3.9.5-301. There must be a keyboard configuration somewhere that needs to be changed??  Note: the Caps Lock feature itself works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the setleds command, see if you can turn the led light on.
In any case, it seems to me that this is bug. I would file a bug in their bugzilla, but Fedora 19 is end of life so I'm not sure if that  possible.

Answer (score 0):

In my grub.cfg file their is this term - console.keymap=us in every linux boot command line. The 3.14.27-100 kernel was part of a complete upgrade with yum. I don't know if this term was always there or if it was part of a revamped grub.cfg file done with the new kernel install.

But here is what solved the problem. I just changed the term to: console.keymap=""   Also, if I took out the term completely it wouldn't change anything-problem still there. Taking it out completely must cause the kernel or some other part of the system to pick up the value - us as a default.

There is bound to be a better, more elegant way of approaching this. There are alot of values that can be assigned to console.keymap that might work.